# Mac M1 , showing wrong ruby version when running bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, ruby-2.0

> ruby -v

---- ruby 2.0.0p598 (2014-11-13 revision 48408) [x86_64-darwin21.2.0]

> rvm list

--- =* ruby-2.0.0-p598 [ x86_64 ]

> bundle install

----- Your Ruby version is 2.6.8, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0

i have ruby 2.0.0 in gemfile and i have set same ruby version in local(please check above command) don't know why its giving error in bundle install
os is mac version 12

Comment: MacOS 12 comes with Ruby 2.6.8 as system version. You may want to check you have a `.ruby-version` file which indicates which version you are using under current directory.

Comment: Hi, i have ruby-2.0.0-p598 in .ruby-version already. i just want to use ruby version that i set using rvm, but its shows only system ruby version.

Comment: Hey did you get any solution. On command ruby --version MAC m1 showing 2.6.8 but when checking with rbenv version it is showing 2.7.5 which i need for running create react-native app. Instead it shows wrong ruby version. Do tell me if you got the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Check your Gemfile, it may be stating to use ruby `2.0.0`. Your options are:

1. Remove that line from your Gemfile and bundle install again.
2. Downgrade your ruby to 2.0.0
3. Update your ruby in the Gemfile to 2.6.8 and bundle install again.

Alternatively check if your project's root contains a .ruby-version file which also may state the version of your project's ruby. If so, steps before are the same.

I recommend you installing some ruby version manager (Like [RVM](https://rvm.io/))